# Error referencing external jquery library in master page

Tags: jquery

Background - I added a webpart to hold my jquery script on a single Sharepoint page.  It works fine.  In the HTML of the source editor, the script begins:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">....
```

Now I want to put that same jquery in the master page to use it site wide.

I copied what I had in the webpart and saved it as js to /scripts/outboundlinks.js

In my master page, I put the following just before the closing head tag:

```
<script src="/Scripts/OutboundLinks.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
```

and saved / approved my master page.

I'm surfing about on my site and the javascipt is not working. Looking at the loaded scripts in IE developer tool I am getting an error that point to the 1st line referencing the external js library.

What does the master page not like about my script that a webpart with this script will allow?   Is it the external reference to jquery?  Do I have to have jquery library local to my sharepoint site?

I could just try this - but I am interested in hearing an explanation for this.
[image]

Comment: sorry for the mulitple edits.  I was getting an error submitting my question until I broke it into pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your script file can contain `<script>` tags.  Try loading the jQuery in your master page directly, then having only script (no `<script>` tags) in the OutboundLinks.js file (loaded after jQuery, of course).  So your master page will have:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/Scripts/OutboundLinks.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
```

OutboundLinks.js will contain:

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        //rest of code...
```

Comment: I'm giving this a try later this evening in production, thank you for the reply.

Comment: That did the trick to take the scripts out of the .js file.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is incorrectly configured. if you start with a / you need everything after .com to be included which should contain at least your site name. Relative paths do not start with / and can be used appropriately. See http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: I think I have to reference the hosted jquery library as such, according to this.. http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/#protocolless